# Why i am able to read/write arraylist at same time?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

i am using multiple threads here .. one thread is fetching the list and other is adding a name to the list and both these threads are using a shared resource ie `ArrayList object` it should give `concurrentModification` something like that which it is not giving or maybe i am not able to use the threads correctly in my code

code is as follows :

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class threadprac  
 {
  public static void main(String args[]){

        ArrayList<String> shared;
         shared = new ArrayList<>(); 
         String[] arr=new String[]{"amol","robin","shanu","saaru","mohit"};
         for(String n:arr)
           shared.add(n);  
         Thread tf = new Thread(new fetch(shared));
         Thread tm = new Thread(new manipulate(shared));
         tm.setName("thread-M"); tf.setName("thread-F");
         tf.start();
         tm.start();
         try {
         Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000); 
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(threadprac.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
         for(String n:shared)
           System.out.print(n+" ");  

 }    
}

class fetch implements Runnable
{
 ArrayList<String> f;
 fetch(ArrayList shared){
   this.f=shared;
   }
 @Override
 public void run(){
  displayList(); 
  }
void displayList(){
   Iterator<String> itr=f.iterator();
   while(itr.hasNext()){
      String name = itr.next();
      System.out.print(name+" ");
   }
   System.out.println();
  } 
}

class manipulate implements Runnable
{
ArrayList<String> m;
manipulate(ArrayList shared){
    this.m=shared;
}
@Override
public void run(){
    addName();
 }
void addName(){
  m.add("rohit"); 
 } 
}
```

Comment: It's never said that we cannot do what you are doing, it's just unsafe to do that and can produce ambiguous results

Comment: @SarthakMittal .. i am using a fail-fast iterator and i am modifying the list after declaring the iterator ...shuldnt this give an exception ? jsut curious

Comment: @SarthakMittal checks for concurrent modification are performed at best-effort basis, as mentioned in documentation, i. e. there is a chance that you won't get an exception.

Comment: Just for the precision: I believe that modifying the list after the iterator is declared, is not enough to provoke the `ConcurrentModificationException`. It will typically be thrown when invoking `next()` or `hasNext()` on the iterator after the list has been modified. It still might happen in your program, though.

Comment: By the way, I sometimes get the `ConcurrentModificationException` when running your program on my Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Thread.start()` takes some time. It's very likely that the first thread has completed before the second begins to use its Iterator -- or vice versa, there's no way to predict which.

One of the problems with concurrency is that we have to use phrases like 'very likely' because we can't predict the order in which things will happen, so the behaviour of some programs becomes inconsistent.

Try putting some `Thread.sleep()` statements inside the loops, so that you can be more sure that the ArrayList `get()`s execute while the `Iterator` is open.

Note that while adding sleeps is a quick and easy way to "fiddle" the timings into long enough periods that you can witness certain conditions occurring, they are almost never the right way to solve thread synchronization issues in real code.

Comment: i used a loop with 100 names ..it gave same result ..ie while fetching i got the added value also ..so that means both threads ran simultaeously and didn't gave any exception

Answer (score 3):

Each of the two threads takes so little time (probably less than 1 microsecond on a modern CPU) that the chance of them actually executing at the same time is extremely low.  You would have to do significant work in both threads to ensure they were active simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

As @Slim mentioned its due to the delay in threads while displaying and adding.
Modify your code as below by adding Sleep, it would result in concurrentModificationException.

```
void displayList() throws InterruptedException {
        Iterator<String> itr = f.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            String name = itr.next();
            Thread.sleep(100);
            System.out.print(name + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

 ...

    void addName() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(100);
    m.add("rohit");
}
```

Exception:

```
amol Exception in thread "thread-F" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
    at fetch.displayList(TestClass.java:43)
    at fetch.run(TestClass.java:33)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Any reason why a downvote? I tested this and I did get a concurrentModifcationException. And the code looks fine as well.

Comment: Seems odd, since you have made an effort to force a `ConcurrentModificationException`, which is somewhat relevant to what the OP wanted to see, but couldn't. I thought this did add some value to the post. +1 from me.

Comment: Sure, I down-voted it. Your opening statement is a false qualifier. Further, recommending a sleep is, at best, not the best.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I agree. but in order to show "that the Exception was initially not occurring was due to a timing issue between the threads", I had to introduce a Sleep. This is just an explanation to show that delay between threads could be the reason (For understanding purpose), but not a code to which needs to be used in a project.

Comment: The timing is necessary but not sufficient to cause a concurrency issue. In a real scenario, even if the threads ran for more time, it wouldn't be guaranteed to be an exception. What troubles me is it's trivial to produce an example that will *naturally* show what OP's after. That would be much better than proposing sleeps.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` is not threadsafe. You should probably be looking at something like [ConcurrentLinkedDeque](http://howtodoinjava.com/core-java/multi-threading/non-blocking-thread-safe-list-concurrentlinkeddeque-example/)

Comment: This answer does not really address the question